# How to set heigth of table row?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I am not trying to do anything fancy, but every row in the table has som sort of padding bottom. It looks like there is a \n in the end of the string.

`+--------------------------------+ 
 |First Cell     | Second Cell    | 
 +--------------------------------+ 
 |Other Cell     | Other Really   | 
 |               | Big Cell       | 
 +--------------------------------+`

I am using extension methods to add each row, I tryed the following comments but they didn't work as intended

```
public static void AddRow(this Table table, string[] cells)
{
    var row = table.AddRow();
    //row.HeightRule = RowHeightRule.Exactly;
    //row.Height = 20;
    //row.BottomPadding = 0;

    var i = 0;
    foreach (var cell in cells)
    {
        row.Cells[i].AddParagraph(cell);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe there is a `\n` at the end of your text, maybe your paragraph format has some SpaceAfter set, maybe something else. Provide a complete working sample or a MDDDL file for inspection. See also: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDocDDL.ashx

Answer (score 0):

as @pdfsharp-team pointed out, there was a `ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 10;` that coused the issue.

Thank you, @pdfsharp-team